# Converting Tensorflow model to PyTorch model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, pytorch, torch

I need to convert my TF model to the PyTorch model. Here's my TF model:

```
def create_convlstm_model():
    
    model = Sequential()
    
    model.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=4, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='tanh', data_format='channels_last',
                        recurrent_dropout=0.2, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(SEQUENCE_LENGTH,   IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH, 3)))
    
    model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(1,2,2), padding='same', data_format='channels_last'))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.2)))
    
    model.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=8, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='tanh', data_format='channels_last',
                        recurrent_dropout=0.2, return_sequences=True))
    
    model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(1,2,2), padding='same', data_format='channels_last'))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.2)))
    
    model.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=14, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='tanh', data_format='channels_last',
                        recurrent_dropout=0.2, return_sequences=True))
    
    model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(1,2,2), padding='same', data_format='channels_last'))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.2)))
    
    model.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='tanh', data_format='channels_last',
                        recurrent_dropout=0.2, return_sequences=True))
    
    model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(1,2,2), padding='same', data_format='channels_last'))
    # model.add(TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.2)))
    
    model.add(Flatten())
    
    model.add(Dense(len(CLASSES_LIST), activation='softmax'))
    
    model.summary()
    
    return model
```

Is there a way to convert it to the PyTorch? I couldn't find ConvLSTM2d in torch.

Comment: You might want to check [PyTorch to TF converter](https://github.com/leonidk/pytorch-tf/blob/master/pytorch-tf.ipynb) of [DL model convertors](https://github.com/ysh329/deep-learning-model-convertor).